# single-spa framework main app calling an sub-app from a remote server

Tags: angular, single-spa-angular

We are using a **single-spa library** in angular to handling our micro-frontends project.
One micro-frontend is the main app that is loading other micro-frontends.
Build files of other sub-app are present inside a new server.

The issue is when we are using node-module with icons like **ag-grid**.
The icons are not fetched because it's using the URL from the main app instead of using the path of the sub-app.

The node_module package should use the path of the remote server instead of the main app.

We found one solution :

- Copy and paste the ag-grid node_module in the assets folder and override the path to target the remote env

This solution is not viable for several reasons (updates are not simple, maintenance of this new codebase, the difference between standalone mod and single-spa mod).

Do you have any ideas on how to make it work?

- reverse proxy
- subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried building a util-module and exporting the icons from the util-module. A util-module can export icons, css and components as needed. Look at the react-styles example from single-spa

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).